How to be logged in two different project in django
I have two Django applications, app1, and app2, both using the same database and running on different ports (localhost:8000 and localhost:8010). When I log in to app1, I want the user to be automatically logged in to app2 as well. Currently, both apps are using the database session engine, but I haven't configured caching yet. I have a plan to set up Redis for caching and session management to enable session sharing between the two applications.

If you want users to be logged into both app1 and app2 at the same time, you can set them up to share session data using Redis. Basically, you’ll need to configure both apps to use Redis for session storage. In the settings.py for both apps, just point the SESSION_ENGINE to Redis, and make sure both apps are using the same Redis instance.
Also, make sure both apps are sharing the same session cookie by setting the same SESSION_COOKIE_NAME and SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN in settings.py. Don't forget to use the same SECRET_KEY for both apps too, so session encryption doesn’t break.
Once that’s set, when a user logs into app1, they should be automatically logged into app2 too because they’ll be sharing the session info from Redis. Give it a quick test to make sure everything’s syncing up right!

can you give an example?
